# First index of number in that arithmetic progression which is a multiple of the given prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a prime number $p$, an arithmetic progression starting at $a$ with common difference $d$. How to find the first index of a term in that arithmetic progression which is a multiple of the given prime number $p$?

Example:
$$
a = 4,\quad
d = 9,\quad
p = 11.
$$

The sequence is $4,13,22,31,\dotsc$; the first index such that the term is divisible by $p$ is $2$, because $22\bmod 2 = 0$.

If no such term exists, give answer as $-1$.

Brute force works but takes a lot of time. Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: You want to solve the equation $a+xd \equiv 0 \ (p)$. So the answer is just $x = -ad^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $d^{-1}$ can be found with the generalized Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $k$-th term of the progression is $a+kd$, so you need to solve
$$
a+kd\equiv0\pmod{p}
$$
or
$$
kd\equiv -a\pmod{p}
$$
which has surely a solution whenever $d$ is not a multiple of $p$; in this case take $e$ an inverse of $d$ modulo $p$, so the equation becomes
$$
k\equiv -ae \pmod{p}
$$

In your example the inverse of $9$ modulo $11$ is $5$, as $9\cdot 5=45\equiv 1\pmod{11}$. So the solution is
$$
k\equiv (-4)\cdot 5\equiv -20\equiv 2\pmod{11}
$$
In general you find the inverse modulo $p$ with the extended Euclidean algorithm.

If $d\equiv0\pmod{p}$ there is no solution.

Comment: Nice Answer , will you please explain how −20≡2(mod11) @egreg

Comment: @Sumeet $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ if and only if $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$; now $-20-2=-22=(-2)\cdot 11$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the interesting case $\gcd(d,p)=1,\;$ i.e. $d$ has in inverse mod p.
You want to solve $a + xd = Ip$. Compute $x=-ad^{-1} \pmod p$ and then the index $I$ is $\frac{a+xd}{p}$.
In your case 
$$9^{-1} \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$$
$$x=-ad^{-1}=(-4\times5) \equiv 2 \pmod {11}$$
$$I = \frac{4+2\times 9}{11}=\frac{22}{11} = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ 11\mid 4+9x\!\iff\! {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ 4+9x\equiv 0\! \iff\! 9x\,\equiv-4\!\iff\!x\,\equiv\,  \dfrac{-4}9 \,\equiv\, \dfrac{-4}{-2} \,\equiv\, 2$

**Remark** $\ $ The familiar arithmetic of $ $ *fractions* $ $ is valid modulo $\,m\,$ as long as one restricts to fractions $\,a/b\,$ with **denominator  coprime to the modulus** $\,m.\,$ Indeed, by Bezout's identity for the gcd, $\,(b,m) = 1\,\Rightarrow\,b\,$ is invertible $ $ mod $\,m,\,$ therefore the fraction has the unique denotation $\,x = a/b = ab^{-1}$ (the unique solution of $\,bx = a).\,$  The usual rules of fraction arithmetic remain true (as long as one restricts to such fractions), e.g. from a prior answer:

**Hint** $\ {\rm  mod}\ 13\!:\  \dfrac{41}7 \equiv  \dfrac{28}7 = 4\ \ $ by $\ \ 41\equiv 41\!-\!13 = 28$

**Alternatively** $\ \dfrac{41}{7}\equiv\dfrac{(-2)(-1)}{-6}\equiv \dfrac{-2}{-2}\dfrac{12}3\equiv 4\ \ $ by $\ \ \begin{eqnarray}41&&\equiv\ \ 2\\ 7 &&\equiv -6\end{eqnarray}$

**Alternatively** $\ \dfrac{41}{7}\equiv \dfrac{2}7\equiv \dfrac{4}{14}\equiv \dfrac{4}1\ $ by [Gauss's Algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

Such fraction twiddling (adding/subtracting the modulus from numerator or denominator till things divide or factor nicely) works  well for small numbers. For larger numbers one can invert the denominator by the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242), or [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) if the modulus is prime.

**Beware** $ $ A fraction with noninvertible denominator (not coprime to  modulus) is not well-defined. For example, mod $\rm\:10,\:$ $\rm\:4\,x\equiv 2\:$ has solutions $\rm\:x\equiv 3,8,\:$ so the "fraction" $\rm\:x \equiv 2/4\pmod{10}\,$ cannot designate a unique solution of $\,4x\equiv 2.\,$ Indeed, the solution is $\rm\:x\equiv 1/2\equiv 3\pmod 5,\,$ which requires canceling $\,2\,$ from the *modulus* too, because $\rm\:10\:|\:4x-2\iff5\:|\:2x-1.\,$ Similarly ill-defined is the fraction $\,x \equiv 1/4\,$ since $\,10\mid 4x-1\,\Rightarrow 10n = 4x-1\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,4x-10 = 1\,$ is even, contradiction. Ring-theoretically, this may be viewed as a generalization of the fact that division by zero is not well-defined, i.e. division by a $\,\rm\color{#c00}{zero\!-\!divisor}\,$ is not well-defined (in a nontrivial ring), since if $\,\color{#c00}{ac=0,\ c\ne 0}\,$ then $\,ax = b\,\Rightarrow\,a(x\!+\!c) = b\,$ so if a solution $\,x\,$ exists then it is not unique.

Generally the grade-school rules of fraction arithmetic apply *universally* (i.e. in all rings) where the denominators are all invertible. This fundamental property will be clarified conceptually when one learns in university algebra about the *universal properties* of fractions rings (and localizations).