# Prime number lists

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

"Find the smallest possible integer n with the property that there exists a prime $p$ such that the $6$ numbers: $p, p+n, p+2n, p+3n, p+4n, p+5n$ are all prime numbers."

Okay, so I have tried what I thought to be every combination of numbers and cannot figure out what works for the last number $p+5n$; I understand that $n$ must be even since if $n$ is odd then there will always be at least $2$ even numbers. which would be a contradiction of all numbers being prime.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated on solving this without brute force.

Comment: How did you try out "every combination of numbers"? Are you implying that you have found $p$ and $n$ that result in $p, p+n, p+2n, p+3n, p+4n$ as prime numbers? Can you put in some more detail of how you found $p$ and $n$?

Comment: you found $n$ must be a multiple of $2$; must $n$ be a multiple of $3$?

Comment: Okay I haven't tried literally every combination I just wanted to see if there was a better way of doing this then brute force.

Comment: No, 3 can't be taken as n.

Comment: an4s I simply went through every k starting from 1 and found n=6 and p=5 to work but it does not work for p+5n since 35 is not prime

Comment: @user287133:  what's $k$ in your last comment?

Comment: Sorry I meant to put n not k

Comment: Cf. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression)

Comment: Consider changing the title to "Prime Numbers in Arithmetic Progression"

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If $n$ is not a multiple of $2$, then $p+n$ or $p+2n$ is.

If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $p+n$ or $p+2n$ or $p+3n$ is.

If $n$ is not a multiple of $5$, then $p+n$ or $p+2n$ or $p+3n$ or $p+4n$ or $p+5n$ is.

With that information, try $p=7$.

Comment: I am confused if n is not a multiple of 5, how is the rest a multiple of 5 without knowing what p is?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882609/first-index-of-number-in-that-arithmetic-progression-which-is-a-multiple-of-the) may help you realize that *one* of $p+n, p+2n, p+3n, p+4n$, or $p+5n$ will be a multiple of $5$ if $n$ is not

Comment: Okay the smallest combination I have realized is p=7 and n=30, is this the smallest?

Comment: Yes, $n$ must be a multiple of $30$, and $p$ cannot be $2, 3, $ or $5$; cf. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression)

Comment: why is it that p cannot be 2,3 or 5 sorry I am confused by that part.

Comment: if $p$ is $2,3, $ or $5$, then $p+30$ is a multiple of $2, 3, $ or $5$, respectively, and therefore not prime